# Joomla 1.5 accessing template outside of Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to access and build a page outside of Joomla. I am mostly concerned with the menu.
It starts to load but I am running into multiple errors with the `mosLoadModules` calls. Is there a way to load these or give the page access to these functions?

```
$directory = '/var/www'; // path to Joomla installation

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $directory);
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS . 'configuration.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$mosConfig_live_site = 'mysitesdomain.com';
```

Comment: What are you trying to do (which directory is outside Joomla where) and what errors do you get where exactly?

Comment: could you please be a little more specific as what you're trying to achieve. check your error log as this will give you a hint as to what might be going wrong

Comment: On a side note delete `DS` constant and use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: actually for Joomla 1.5 using `DS` is actually the correct thing to do although it should be defined as `define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  );`

Comment: It is in a secure directory outside of the normal webroot. I don't want to load this via an iframe.

Comment: @E_p - `DS` is already defined in Joomla 1.5. It is deprecated in Joomla 2.5 and was removed in 3.0